# Secure Store Service Application not available in SharePoint 2010 Standard

Tags: service-application, secure-store

We have migrated from SharePoint 2010 foundation to SharePoint 2010 standard. Now, the problem is we are looking for Secure Store Service on 'Services on Server' page in Central Administration, but we didn't see it. We have another server where SharePoint 2010 standard is installed and there we can see Secure Store Service available. Please let me know what needs to be done for the same.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried provisioning a new Secure Store Service?

Answer (score 1):

this tutorial should help http://fabiangwilliams.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/how-to-create-configure-consume-sharepoint-2010-secure-store-in-business-connectivity-services/

Thanks,